# lwuit table X Y scrollable does not work symultaneously

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit, lwuit-form

I am trying to we both vertical and horizontal scrollable of a table in lwuit but there is a problem. When i set the horizontal scrollable it disables the vertical scrollable automatically. The following is the code:

```
t.setScrollableX(true);
t.setScrollable(true);
```

I guess both the scrollable don't work simultaneously. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to put the `Form`'s scrollable property to `false`? I think that you should try it using `setScrollable(false);`

Comment: But by this i am able to scroll from the right hand side of the phone but cannot scroll by dragging the content. Is it possible to do like this?

Comment: I suppose that if you build the components inside the table, scrollables, you will be able to drag inside them, but I think that the app will ran very slow